# Shape error in tensorflow: ValueError: Shapes (8, 1, 128) and (8, 128) are incompatible

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I am trying to train a machine learning model (LSTM) with tensorflow. I feed the network a dataset where the input is a vector of shape (batch_size, 4, 128) and the label is of shape (batch_size, 1, 128).

Somehow I get this error

```
    ValueError: Shapes (8, 1, 128) and (8, 128) are incompatible
```

It seems like it one of the axis of the label is removed, but not on the input, so they do not match.

This is my model

```py
  input_shape = (INPUT_LENGTH, 128)
  
  inputs = tf.keras.Input(input_shape)
  x = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(512)(inputs)

  outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="softmax", name='piano_roll')(x)

  model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

  loss = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()

  optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE)

  
  model.compile(
    loss=loss,
    optimizer=optimizer,
  )
```

In order to reshape the output to match the shape of the label, I have tried to add

```py
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((1, 128))(outputs)
```

but then i get this error:

```
ValueError: Unexpected result of `train_function` (Empty logs). Please use `Model.compile(..., run_eagerly=True)`, or `tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)` for more information of where went wrong, or file a issue/bug to `tf.keras`.
```

But when i try to add run_eagerly=True to my model.compile, nothing changes.

Comment: Have you tried to reshape (8, 1, 128) into (8, 128)?

Comment: Yes @Iya, i tried with 
`outputs = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((1, 128))(outputs)`
But I get the value error described in the question.

Comment: Why (1, 128) and not (8, 128)?

Comment: 8 is the batch_size, so if the forward process is called 8 times with input of shape either (1,4,128) or (4, 128) (not sure which). Therefore it can not reshape it to (8, 128) because it is to big of a shape. @Iya